# Default colors given in tailwind documentation are not working

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

I was trying to use colors such as amber and lime, which are mentioned in the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#default-color-palette). These colors didn't work. Only colors with names such as the primary color name (eg. red, pink) worked.

Colors which are not working: amber, emerald, lime, rose, fuchsia, slate, zinc, and even orange.

I'm using version 2.26, but I used the Tailwind playground to check the versions between 1.9 and 2.25, and still these colors didn't work. Even in the playground, these color names are not suggested.

Why can't I use these colors?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is documentation for Tailwind **version 3**, it has [expanded color palette](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors).

You either need to update to version 3 or [use version 2 documentation](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#extending-the-defaults) and expand palette manually, like that:

```
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // you can either spread `colors` to apply all the colors
        ...colors,
        // or add them one by one and name whatever you want
        amber: colors.amber,
        emerald: colors.emerald,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[More info about v2 color customization](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#curating-colors)

[Color palette reference v2](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#color-palette-reference)

So, just read this v2 docs if you want to configure your palette.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this one. I had actually tried using the color names on version3 at tailwind playground but i had not overridden the config file and tried so I could not get those colors. ref-( https://play.tailwindcss.com/gbngSXMwJt?file=config) .

Comment: Again, what you have linked is a v2 playground, not v3. There is selector in the top right corner to chose version. Here is v3 playground with colors working out of the box https://play.tailwindcss.com/AD4gMp7Nxm

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                   //just add this below and your all other tailwind colors willwork
                ...colors
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves my issue since I added color after theme bracket, not inside extend bracket. Thanks Huzaifa

Comment: smart and elegant solution!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the PostCSS 7 Compatibility Build (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat) then you'll need to add the colours to `tailwind.config.js` like so:

```js
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                stone: colors.warmGray,
                sky: colors.lightBlue,
                neutral: colors.trueGray,
                gray: colors.coolGray,
                slate: colors.blueGray,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**
I was having the same issue (with the Compatibility Build) so I did some digging and found the following in `colors.d.ts`, which means you can add the above to the `tailwind.config.js` file in your project to use those same colours with their v3 utility class names (e.g. "*bg-neutral-800*").

```
/**
 * @deprecated renamed to 'sky' in v2.2
 */
lightBlue: TailwindColorGroup;
/**
 * @deprecated renamed to 'stone' in v3.0
 */
warmGray: TailwindColorGroup;
/**
 * @deprecated renamed to 'neutral' in v3.0
 */
trueGray: TailwindColorGroup;
/**
 * @deprecated renamed to 'gray' in v3.0
 */
coolGray: TailwindColorGroup;
/**
 * @deprecated renamed to 'slate' in v3.0
 */
blueGray: TailwindColorGroup;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was I was generating the class name in a VUE component (vite build) via a computed property as such:

```
stateColor() {
  return this.item.state === "filled" ? 'lime-600' :
      this.item.state === 'partial' ? 'yellow-600' :
          this.item.state === 'rejected' ? 'red-600' :
              'gray-600'
}
```

and

```
<div :class="'bg-' + stateColor"></div>
```

It worked after I changed it so that the computed property included the prefix `bg-`:

```
stateColor() {
  return this.item.state === "filled" ? 'bg-lime-600' :
      this.item.state === 'partial' ? 'bg-yellow-600' :
          this.item.state === 'rejected' ? 'bg-red-600' :
              'bg-gray-600'
}
```

and

```
<div :class="stateColor"></div>
```

I think with this setup makes so tailwind doesn't load the appropriate color classes unless it finds a usage, so avoiding (too) dynamically generated names is needed.