# When I add the material tailwind configuration to the tailwind.config file I lose the colors available for bg or border like zinc among many others

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, material-ui, tailwind-css

Do you know if i need other configuration ?

```
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");

module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});
```

When I make the following configuration to use some components as Material Dialog, the rest of my previously implemented layout is modified as it does not detect multiple tailwind colors for example
Zinc, Sky, Indigo and many others

Comment: Hi if someone has the some problem i found the solution here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70704377/default-colors-given-in-tailwind-documentation-are-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Hi if someone has the some problem i found the solution here. You need to add colors configuration.
[Default colors given in tailwind documentation are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70704377/default-colors-given-in-tailwind-documentation-are-not-working)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).